# MySql multiple delete statements

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-delete

I couldn't find anything here or google that works for me.

I have tried the following code:

```
delete from wms where barcode = '65025351102908' and '105077351106577';
```

values are a varchar bear in mind.

No errors come up, but 0 rows are affected. But they are definitely out there.

Comment: Think about your logic.  Do you think `where barcode = '65025351102908' and '105077351106577'` will ever return anything?  For a row, barcode can only either be '65025351102908' or '105077351106577', not both. Also I'm surprised if your code even run.

Comment: Hi Eric, it did run. but deleted everything :(

Comment: Syntax is not valid.  I'm not sure how can it run.

Comment: Bear in mind, thats what I have tried. Its an idea what in trying to do.. its not suppose to work

Comment: **Do not do this** : `where barcode = '65025351102908' OR '105077351106577'` The second statement will **always be true** since it will be different from a falsy value and **delete all entries** @Eric I flagged your (unwillingly) dangerous comment

Comment: @Cid Where do I suggest `where barcode = '65025351102908' OR '105077351106577'`?  I just told OP that for a single row, a bar code can only be '65025351102908' or '105077351106577'.  Nothing about creating a statement as you said.  His issue is it's always returning nothing.  I described that his logic is wrong.  Next time read properly before flagging.

Comment: @Eric it was misintrepreted by OP and may be misinterpreted by others. *"Hi Eric, it did run. but deleted everything :("*

Answer (score 4):

Your `WHERE` clause isn't working as you expect. You can't factorise conditions such way

Writting this will only remove `65025351102908` :

```
WHERE barcode = '65025351102908' and '105077351106577';
--    ^------------------------^     ^---------------^
--          Condition 1                 Condition 2 (always true because different than a falsy value)
```

I suppose you want to remove both `65025351102908` and `105077351106577`

This is done using a OR (remove where the id is equal to the first one OR the second one)

Try this instead :

```
delete from wms where barcode = '65025351102908' or barcode = '105077351106577';
```

If you have a lot of barecode to remove, you can use the `IN` operator :

```
delete from wms where barcode IN ('65025351102908', '105077351106577');
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to delete the two rows with those two values?

Then do this:

```
delete from wms 
where (barcode = '65025351102908') or (barcode = '105077351106577');
```

You can also do this:

```
delete from wms 
where barcode in ('65025351102908','105077351106577');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to delete "between" those values (taking in mind that you are writing them inside single quotes as string) your syntax could be better like this:

```
delete from wms where barcode BETWEEN  '65025351102908' and '105077351106577';
```